# Dynamic form : Throwing error i.e. Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

**Kendo + Angular 6**

While creating Dynamic form using formBuilder in Angular 6 able to render all HTML elements(like Input , Checkbox, Select, Button). But once try to render Kendo component it is throwing error.
[image]

```
`<div 
  class="dynamic-field form-input" 
  [formGroup]="group">
  <label>{{ config.label }}</label>
  <input
    type="text"
    [(ngModel)] = "config.sValue"
    [attr.placeholder]="config.placeholder"
    [formControlName]="config.name" />
</div>
<div class="example-wrapper">
<kendo-autocomplete
    [data]="config.listItems"
    [value]="config.sValue"
    class="countries"
>
</kendo-autocomplete>
```

`

Comment: can you please provide the code snippet you tried so far.

Comment: @HarisyamM : Updated the code snippet. As it has one HTML input element and other is kendo autocomplete. The kendo autocomplete component is throwing error once we click inside the elements.